# Are nested PHP includes CPU/memory intensive?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, include, cpu-usage

I'm coding a site in PHP and getting "pretty urls" (also hiding my directories) by directing all requests to one index.php file (using .htaccess). The index file then parses the uri and includes the requested files. These files also have more than a couple of includes in them, and each may open up a MySQL connection. And then *those* files have includes too, which open sql connections. It goes down to about 3-4 levels.

Is this process CPU and memory intensive, both from the PHP includes and opening (and closing) MySQL connections in each included file?

Also, would pretty urls using purely htaccess use less resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## PHP Overheads

The answer re the logical decomposition of your app into a source hierarchy depends on how your solution is being hosted.

- If you use a dedicated host/VM then you will probably have mod_php+Xcache or equiv and the answer will be: no, it doesn't really hit the runtime since everything gets cached in-memory at the PHP Opcode level.
- If you use a shared hosting service then it *will* impact performance since any PHP scripts will be loaded through PHP-cgi probably via suPHP and the entire source hierarchy that is included will need to be read in and compiled ***per request***.  Worse, on a shared solution, if this request is the first in say 1 min, then the servers file cache will have been flushed and marshalling this source will involve a lot of physical I/O = seconds time delay.

I administer a few phpBB forums and have found that by aggregating common include hierarchies for shared hosting implementations, I can half the user response time. Here are some are articles which describe this in more detail ([Terry Ellison [phpBB]](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-phpBB)).  And to quote one article:

> Let me quantify my views with some ballpark figures.  I need to emphasise that the figures below are indicative.  I have included the benchmarks as attachments to this article, just in case you want to validate them on your own service.
>
> - **20–40**.  The number of files that you can open and read per second, if the file system cache is not primed.
> - **1,500–2,500**.  The number of files that you can open and read per second, if the file system cache is primed with their contents.
> - **300,000–400,000**.  The number of lines per second that the PHP interpreter can compile.
> - **20,000,000**.  The number of PHP instructions per second that the PHP interpreter can interpret.
> - **500-1,000**.  The number of MySQL statements per second that the PHP interpreter can call, if the database cache is primed with your table contents.

For more see [More on optimising PHP applications in a Webfusion shared service](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-44) where you can copy the benchmarks to run yourself.

## MySQL connection

The easiest thing to do here is to pool the connection.  I use my own mysqli class extension which uses a standard single-object-per-class template.  In my case any module can issue a:

```
$db = AppDB::get();
```

to return this object.  This is cheap as it is an internal call involve half a dozen PHP opcodes.

An alternative but traditional method is to use a global to hold the object and just do a

```
global $db;
```

in any function that need to use it.

### Footnote for Small Applications

You suggested combining all includes into a single include file.  This is OK for stable production, but a **pain** during testing.  Can I suggest a simple compromise?  Keeps them separate for testing but allow loading of a single composite.  You do this in two parts (i) I assume each include defines a function or class, so use a standard template for each include, e.g.

```
if( !function_exists( 'fred' ) ) {
    require "include/module1.php";
}
```

Before any loads in the master script simple do:

```
@include "include/_all_modules.php";
```

This way, when you are test you delete `_all_modules.php` and the script falls back to loading individual modules.  When you're happy you can recreate the `_all_modules.php`.  You can event do this server side by a simple "release" script which does a

```
system( 'cp include/[a-z]*.php include/_all_modules.php' );
```

This way, you get the best of both worlds

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I'm on a shared environment. Although the articles you linked to seem like a lot more info than I need, what I took from them is that I should use less includes, simplify what's in the included files, and use one connection during the entire request. Thanks!

Comment: Yves, +1 on the MySQL connection.  I've also added a stripped down suggestion for aggregating includes that you might be comfortable with. :-)

Comment: Thanks again, Terry. I've been separating the includes into files based on their function for easier debugging, but based on what's suggested here I'm thinking of rearranging them instead based on how often they're used. Put all the commonly used methods in one file and keep the others (that aren't used in every page) in one or two smaller files, to avoid including methods when they aren't going to be used anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the MySQL client code, I know for one that connections often get reused when opening a MySQL connection with the same parameters.

Personally I wouldd only initialize the database connection in the front controller (your index.php file), because everything should come through there anyway.

Comment: This is a good point. By having `.htaccess` *and* PHP checking and parsing to work out what content to include, you're essentially performing the same job twice in two different locations. This will make your code harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep just one connection open through the entire request, then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `include_once()` or `require_once()` methods to ensure that PHP only parses them once, thus saving processing time. This would be particularly valuable if you suspect that your code might attempt to include files more than once per script execute.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

I would imagine that using `.htaccess` to parse URLs would always use more resources than any other method, purely because those rules would be activated upon every single `.php` file request your server encountered.

Comment: Not quite, if you strace apache2 with the -X option then you will see that processing the .htaccess takes ~2 mSec.  Just using `<?php echo "hello world";?>` takes ~100 mSec on a shared hosting service (which are typically suPHP based).  The `.htaccess` opens one user file, and the PHP typically dozens.